# Creating Json structure from Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, mapreduce

I have dataframe which is product of left join. Now I want to create json structure.

I tried using different option but I was not able create it. Here is my dataframe :

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
1111    name    aaa     bbb
1111    name    ccc     ddd
1111    name    iii     kkk
1112    name1   abcd    def
1112    name1   DEFG    ABXC
```

The desired json structure is:

```
{col1: 1111, col2: name, details: [{col3: aaa, col4: bbb}, {col3: ccc, col4: ddd}, {col3: iii, col4: kkk}]},
{col1: 1112, col2: name1, details: [{col3: abcd, col4: def}, {col3: DEFG, col4: ABXC}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = df.withColumn("details", f.to_json(f.struct("col3", "col4")))
df = df.groupBy(*["col1", "col2"]).agg(f.collect_list("details").alias("details"))

df.write.format('json').save('/path/file_name.json')
```